# Pause File Processing In Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route which looks like this, the first route reads from the file

```
from("file:verylargefile.csv")
.multicast()
.parallelProcessing()
.to(directEndpoint)).end()


from(directEndpoint)
   .routeId(routeId)
   .routePolicy(routePolicy)
   .process(proxyFieldProcessor)
   .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
   .to(http-endpoint);
```

I need to pause the file processing if there are too many bad responses from rest endpoints. i am using custom route policy on the second  route, this does suspend the second route  but the first route keeps sending messages to second route which results in `org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException`

is there any other way to pause file processing in camel?

Answer (score 0):

One approach to exactly do that can be to implement an error handler in the 2nd route, that uses the ControlBus component to suspend the 1st one:

```
controlbus:route?routeId=foo&action=suspend
```

Comment: thanks for the response, the first route is file processing route it reads a very large file if I try to suspend that route it runs to completion before suspension

Comment: In my opinion this is due to Camel's default behavior to process Inflight Exchanges *graceful*, related to shutdown strategies, see https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/graceful-shutdown.html

Comment: yes suspending first route is not an option that is why I tried suspending the second route which gets it exchanges from first route, but first route keeps sending messages to second route after second route is suspended that is why I am getting DirectConsumerNotAvailableException

Comment: My original answer referred to your question about how to interrupt the file processing. This can be done -- cleanly -- only within the constraints of Camel, as mentioned. Since there is already an Exchange in processing on the first route, it must be processed, even if it fails. With the current setup of the routes this seems to me to be the expected behaviour.  Beyond your original question, you can of course explore other alternatives, such as using `redeliveryDelay` with a `redeliveryPolicyProfile`.